# choosing ajax url datatable

Tags: javascript, datatable

i want to choose datatable ajax url whether its containingdata1 , containingdata2  or containingdata3 .

here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $table = $('#datatable1');
    $table.DataTable({
      "columnDefs": [
                     {"className": "dt-center", "targets": "_all"}
                    ],  
   if(containdata1){
   ajax: {
           url: "/api/dunapi/"+containdata1,
                type: 'GET'
            },

   if(containdata2){
    ajax: {  
        url  : "/api/dunapi/"+containdata2,
        type : 'GET'                      
            },
   
   }
   if(containdata3){
    ajax: {  
        url  : "/api/dunapi/"+containdata3,
        type : 'GET'                      
            },
   
   }
```

i want to do it  like that if it can possibly be done

Comment: change to `ajax = {...}`?

Comment: still, It cant be choosed.

Comment: i think. what you mean is, you need to wrap your data call into a method and pass your variable into this methid

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to merge data from many data source, then it would be best to gather the data outside of DataTable. Use jQuery's ajax() function (Or any JavaScript client like axios) to get all the data, merge it together into a single object, and pass into DataTables's data option.

Like:

```
var data = []

if(containdata1){
    await axios.get("/api/dunapi/"+containdata1).then(res => {
        data = data.concat(res.data)
    })
}
if(containdata2){
    await axios.get("/api/dunapi/"+containdata2).then(res => {
        data = data.concat(res.data)
    })
}
if(containdata3){
    await axios.get("/api/dunapi/"+containdata3).then(res => {
        data = data.concat(res.data)
    })
}
```

then when define your datatable:

```
{
// datatable options
data: data
.....
}
```

Note: you should add `async` before ready function because we are using await before each request:

```
$(document).ready(async function() {
......
}
```

Comment: i want that 3 variable get inside my datatable url,
not just by 1.

Comment: check the edits